# Filtered Column Also Shows in Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet file that compares one column to another, and all that matches will mark the cell as green through conditional formatting. The non-existent data will be marked as red.

[image]

Everything is working perfectly but when I try to filter Column C, it will still show as green in the checker even though it's not showing in my filter.

I looked up online and found the subtotal function but I can't seem to incorporate it into my existing formula.

Here's my formula for Green.

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C,$G2)>0
```

Here's my formula for Red.

```
=AND(LEN(G2),COUNTIF($C$1:$C,$G2)=0)
```

The filter happens before the addition of data in Column G. As you can see below, I filtered Canada and then added Canada in the Checker and it shows as Green, which shouldn't.
[image]

Comment: Your current formula should work in filtered cells. What result do you get right now?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion but the filter happens before the addition of data in Column G. I updated the original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUBTOTAL is the only function that detects hidden values. You can use it to filter the values inside your COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(C:C,BYROW(C:C,LAMBDA(e,SUBTOTAL(103,e)))),$G2)>0
```

It takes each row and counts how many unhidden values are there. Then if the result is 0, it gets filtered out

Comment: I tried this formula on my sheet but it seems to be too slow. I currently have more than 2000 data and whenever I type in Column G, the loading bar shows up. I previously tried to add another column with SUBTOTAL that shows 0 and 1 but I can't seem to make that work on my current formula.

Comment: Guessing you have it in an auxiliary column D:D you can try: =COUNTIF(FILTER(C:C,D:D),$G2)>0 . Or simply use the filter in the auxiliary column, instead of displaying 1 and 0s make it display only the filtered data and just use =COUNTIF(D:D.... In the conditional formatting

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin! FILTER(C:C.D:D) worked for me and it's fast as well. I really appreciate your help.